# Keras loaded model input change

Tags: keras

Do you have any idea of an easy way to modify input image size of a saved model in Keras? For example the training input image size is 32x32, but in test I would like to input the full image 180x180. The model has been saved and at test loaded as the following:
    `json_file = open('autoencoder64a.json', 'r')
    loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
    json_file.close()
    loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
    # load weights into new model
    loaded_model.load_weights("autoencoder64a.h5")`

Many thanks,
Tina

Answer (score 0):

Is this a fully convolutional net? Otherwise you will not be able to reuse it with different input size, as this will change the number of weights in the non-convolutional layers.

If it is indeed a FCN, you only need to change the first and last line in the code defining the model:

```
    input_layer = Input((180,180))
    #All other layers copied here from your old model, 
    #ending with 'last_layer =...'
    new_model = Model(input_layer, last_layer)
```